# How to upload images gotten from camera using Android Upload Service

Tags: java, android, android-studio, upload

I have been able to make users upload photos to server taken from their gallery, but when a user uses camera to capture live and upload, I get this error **unsupported scheme: file::///storage/...**

I am using android upload service library

```
implementation "net.gotev:uploadservice:3.5.2"
```

I searched and discovered that file:// scheme is not allowed to be attached with Intent.

**1. Selecting image from camera on button click**

```
capture_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, 
 FileProvider.getUriForFile(UploadActivity2.this, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", 
 createImageFile()));
                startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });
```

**2. Getting the image captured**

```
if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
        switch (requestCode){
            case 0:
  try {
                 Uri cameraPath =    FileProvider.getUriForFile(UploadActivity2.this, 
  BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", createImageFile());
                 String stringUri = cameraPath.toString();
                 selectedImages.add(stringUri);

                }catch (IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
 Glide.with(this)
                        .load(cameraFilePath)
                        .into(display_image);
 break;
        }
     }
```

As you see, I am using file provider to get Uri and storing the uri in a variable called **selectedimages** so I can pass it through an intent to another activity where the upload occurs

*createImageFile method*

```
  private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.UK).format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
    //This is the directory in which the file will be created. This is the default location of Camera photos
    File storageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM), "Camera");
    File image = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,  /* prefix */
            ".jpg",         /* suffix */
            storageDir      /* directory */
    );
    // Save a file: path for using again
    cameraFilePath = "file://" + image.getAbsolutePath();
    return image;
   }
```

**3. Passing intent PATH, to uploadActivity**

```
next_upload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(UploadActivity2.this, UploadActivity3.class);
            intent.putStringArrayListExtra("PATH", selectedImages);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

**5. UploadAcvity where the upload happens**

```
public void upload() {
    ArrayList<String> selectedImages = getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("PATH");
try {
        String uploadId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

        //Creating a multi part request
        new MultipartUploadRequest(this, uploadId, EndPoints.UPLOAD_URL)
                .addFileToUpload(selectedImages.get(0), "image") //Adding file
                .addParameter("caption", captionx) //Adding text parameter to the request
                .setNotificationConfig(new UploadNotificationConfig())
                .setMaxRetries(0)
                .startUpload(); //Starting the upload

    } catch (Exception exc) {
        Toast.makeText(this, exc.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Using this.

a. The image is not displaying in **point 2** using **Glide.with(this)
                                .load(cameraFilePath)
                                .into(display_image);**

b. The image uploads but it is an empty file of 0 bytes.

But when I change the value of the variable of **selectedImages** in point **2** from **selectedImages.add(stringUri);** to **selectedImages.add(cameraFilePath);**

b. After clicking upload, I get error **unsupported scheme: file::///storage/**

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer.

**1.** In the **createImageFile method**. I had to get the coontent:// url from the captured file using -

```
File newFile = new File(storageDir, image.getName());
    contentUrl = FileProvider.getUriForFile(UploadActivity2.this, 
BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", newFile);
    stringContentUrl = contentUrl.toString();
```

**2.** Then I passed the stringContentUrl into selected images String while getting the image captured.

```
selectedImages.add(stringContentUrl);
```

**3.** Passed it through an intent Extra and called it in the uploadActivity as seen in point **3** and **4** in the question.